# How to set expiry address on a queue in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I have a Spring Boot 3 app which use ActiveMQ Artemis. The application creates it own queue, and I want to set the expiry address of the queues in the Spring Boot app (i.e. not by editing the `broker.xml`). However, I did not find any information about that in the official documentation.

It seems not possible to set it in the web administration console either.

Comment: Is the Spring Boot application managing the instance of ActiveMQ Artemis? Are you configuring the broker programmatically or via `application.yml` or `application.properties`?

Comment: The broker is not embedded. For the configuration the conection factory is built automatically with the application.yml, and thé queues programmatically

Comment: If the broker is not embedded with the client in your application then how do you expect to control where the broker sends expired messages from your application?

Comment: I do not know this is m'y question, maybe it is not possible. It is possible to create queue  dynamically with the Spring starter so it might be possible to do do with address-settings (but maybe it is not)

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the broker isn't embedded you won't be able to control it directly. You'll either have to modify the broker's `broker.xml` or use [remote management](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management).

In `broker.xml` the expiry address is set via the `expiry-address` address setting. This is described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-expiry.html#configuring-expiry-addresses), e.g.:

```xml
...
<address-settings>
   ...
   <!-- expired messages in exampleQueue will be sent to the expiry address expiryQueue -->
   <address-setting match="exampleQueue">
      <expiry-address>expiryQueue</expiry-address>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>
...
<addresses>
   ...
   <address name="exampleQueue">
      <anycast>
         <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
      </anycast>
   </address>
   <address name="expiryQueue">
      <anycast>
         <queue name="expiryQueue"/>
      </anycast>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

You can also add address-settings to the broker via the web administration console using one of the `addAddressSettings` operations.

Comment: I Justin thanks for tout response but I think my question was not clear enough. I want to set the expiry address in m'y Spring boot app not in the broker.xml configuration file

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that helps!